# Move non-contiguous cell contents in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In my current Excel worksheet, I would like to move the selected non-contiguous cell contents to the right and up, from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

I tried the following macro:

```
Sub move()

Selection.Offset(-1, 1).Value = Selection.Value
Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

but ended up with this:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the contents of A5 and A8 after moving? Thanks!

**EDIT :** Finally, is it possible to delete the original rows (A2, A5, and A8 in my example) after moving the selected cell contents?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It's a huge relief to know I won't have to move a couple of thousand non-contiguous cells manually. Cheers!

Comment: That's right. If your question is resolved, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this....

```
Sub TransformData()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Offset(-1, 1) = cell
    Next cell
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally do not like the use of `Selection` but if you insist, the following may help.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngTemp As Range
    For Each rngTemp In Selection.Areas
        rngTemp.Copy Destination:=rngTemp.Offset(-1, 1)
        rngTemp.ClearContents
    Next rngTemp

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ I agree. I also do not like using selection unless there is absolutely no other way

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each aCell In Selection
        aCell.Cut Destination:=aCell.Offset(-1, 1)
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No select copy data.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Set rngDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas.Count
    For i = 1 To n
        Set rng = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas(i)
        rng(rng.Rows.Count).Copy rng.Range("a1").Offset(, 1)
        rng(rng.Rows.Count).Clear
    Next i
End Sub
```